# Conditional Formatting percent incorrect Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have the following:

[image]

So I want

```
99% and above = Green
Between 95% - 99% = Amber
Below 95% = Red
```

However above 95% is still red.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you pick "percentage", this takes the values as a percentage of all the values. Since you're formatting based on the value itself, and not the value as a percentage of all the other values, you need to use 'Number' for the type and use `0.99` for the upper bound and `0.95` for the lower bound.

**EDIT:** It looks like the behaviour is different in Excel 2016 and one needs to actually put `99` and `95` (and not `0.99` and `0.95`) as values. I guess Microsoft received some complaints or something and decided to change it.

Comment: First, there is no "Percentage" selection, it's "Percent". But what does "percentage of all the values" mean?

Comment: @Suncat2000 It means that if you have 10 rows of values, it would be the percentage of the of all the 10 values. If you try to make a conditional formatting by percentage on such rows with values 10% to 100%, with the top 90% being red, none of the values will be formatted as red because even the one with 100% would be at around 18% of the total [18% = 100% / (10% + 20% + ... + 100%)]. OP is really looking for formatting by value and not by percentage. Like I said in the edit addendum though, this behaviour has been changed in excel 2016. And yes, it was 'Percentage' before excel 2016.