# icon conditional formatting in excel not working

Tags: excel

I can't figure out why my conditional formatting is not working on this one worksheet/table in excel.   All of the icons should be green since the values are greater than 90. Other worksheets are working fine.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Formatting percent incorrect Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881624/conditional-formatting-percent-incorrect-excel)

Comment: @Aprillion: Thank you for down voting my answer. Will take this into account in future.

Comment: to explain for other people: @AxelRichter moved his answer to the original question after I marked this one for closing as duplicate

Comment: @Aprillion: The hint would have been enough. Why down voting was necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate:
[Conditional Formatting percent incorrect Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881624/conditional-formatting-percent-incorrect-excel)

[image: Example:]

Comment: That worked, thank you.  Still baffled as to why this worked on other worksheets with the same parameters.  Oh well...

Comment: @seaveylp: It works using type percent and percentages as the data if the maximum value 100% and also the minimum value 0% is somewhere within the data.

Answer (score 0):

Put conditions as values, not % - change values into 0.9 and 0.801 and change type from % into Value.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Still baffled as to why this worked on other worksheets with the same parameters. Oh well...

Comment: @seaveylp It's because percents are relative - which means that from the range of values it's calculated which values are in group of 33%, 67% of value range - not sure if it's clear, so please refer to following (more clear) explanation: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/icon-sets.html

Comment: Thanks, @Rufus, for that link. Wow, what a screwy way to do things. How very Microsoft to define a counter-intuitive new meaning for "percent". Sort of like saying, "2 + 3 = 32", because our hidden formula replaces your numbers with our powers of 2 and your addition with our multiplication. Instead of using "Percent", they should have labeled that format, "Surprise".