# Excel icon set for conditional format shows wrong icons

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table with some % values in it.
For some reason the conditional formatting seems off.

For example, see (crappy picture sorry as its on an air-gapped system)

I cant understand why the top right 43% and 45%'s are red? It doesnt make sense.

Any ideas?
Ive played around with changing to "number" and moving the values, but still teh oddity remains.

https://m.imgur.com/gallery/k54hfLX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Formatting percent incorrect Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881624/conditional-formatting-percent-incorrect-excel)

Comment: Change to "number" and make the values 0.67 and 0.33.

Comment: Ah thanks guys, Yes seems to be a duplicate (couldnt find that before)
Why on earth it states percent but doesnt work is beyond me.

Comment: It does work - because it's not looking at the actual values (43% and 45%), but rather at those values compared to the entire set in question.